# findViewById returning null while binding ViewHolder (inside nested RecyclerView)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to use a nested RecyclerView, so that I can have a list of custom views that is determined at runtime via an API.

The issue I'm having however is that, after inflating the nested RecyclerView's layout, and attempting to bind it to display my data, I get a NullPointerException from findViewById returning a null. Here's what I'm working with:

**Outer RecyclerView Adapter (onBindViewHolder)**

```
val objectivesRecyclerView: RecyclerView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.objectivesHolder)

val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(ctx, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
objectivesRecyclerView.apply {
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager
    val adapter = ObjectivesAdapter()
    this.adapter = adapter
    adapter.setObjectivesList(pursuit.objectives)
}
```

**Inner RecyclerView's Adapter/Holder**

```
class ObjectivesAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjectivesAdapter.ObjectivesHolder>() {

    private var objectives = arrayListOf<DataClass>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ObjectivesHolder {
        //val inflatedView = parent.inflate(R.layout.objectives_item, false)
        val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.objectives_item, parent, false)
        return ObjectivesHolder(inflatedView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = objectives.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ObjectivesHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindObjective(objectives[position])
    }

    class ObjectivesHolder(var baseView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(baseView), View.OnClickListener {
        private var objectiveTitleText: TextView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.objective_text)
        private val objectiveProgressBar: ProgressBar = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.objective_progress)
        private val objectiveCheckBox: CheckBox = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.completion_checkbox)

        // NullPointerException occurs here, and also happens if I move the calls to bindObjective as well
        // Have also swapped out itemView with baseView instead, with the same results

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {}

        fun bindObjective(objective: DataClass) {
            objectiveTitleText.text = objective.objectiveDefinition.progressDescription
            objectiveProgressBar.progress = objective.progress / objective.objectiveDefinition.completionValue
            objectiveCheckBox.isChecked = objective.progress >= objective.objectiveDefinition.completionValue
        }

    }

}
```

And, the stack trace as well (which points towards the init of the inner recyclerview class)

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.objective_text) must not be null
        at xyz.omnicron.apps.android.dot.ui.objectives.ObjectivesAdapter$ObjectivesHolder.<init>(ObjectivesAdapter.kt:34)
        at xyz.omnicron.apps.android.dot.ui.objectives.ObjectivesAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ObjectivesAdapter.kt:20)
        at xyz.omnicron.apps.android.dot.ui.objectives.ObjectivesAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ObjectivesAdapter.kt:13)
```

I'm sure the issue has something to do with how the inner recyclerview is being initialized / bound, but maybe a fresh pair of eyes can help me isolate the issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit:

[ObjectivesAdapater](https://github.com/russjr08/DOT-Android/blob/objectives-list-item/app/src/main/java/xyz/omnicron/apps/android/dot/ui/objectives/ObjectivesAdapter.kt) => The "inner" RecyclerView's Adapter

[PursuitsAdapter](https://github.com/russjr08/DOT-Android/blob/objectives-list-item/app/src/main/java/xyz/omnicron/apps/android/dot/ui/pursuits/PursuitsAdapter.kt) => The "outer" RecyclerView's Adapter

[PursuitsFragment](https://github.com/russjr08/DOT-Android/blob/objectives-list-item/app/src/main/java/xyz/omnicron/apps/android/dot/ui/pursuits/PursuitsFragment.kt#L49) => Where the outer RecyclerView is initialized, data is set in the startUpdateLoop function.

Comment: did you initialize the second recylcerview ? `val secondRecyclerview: RecyclerView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondrecyclerview)`

Comment: @forthelulx Yep! That is the first line in the "outer" RecyclerView's bind function


``` val objectivesRecyclerView: RecyclerView = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.objectivesHolder) ```

Comment: Im talking about both of them, you need to init the second one  once you know that the first one is populated

Comment: Yes, the outer one is initialized in the Fragment of my Activity, and displays everything just fine within its Layout, until I try to add the inner RecyclerView, which is also initialized after the outer one is up and ready.

Comment: can you add your code? where do you initialize it. the error thrown indicates that --a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time-- which means your view was not ready to be populated. so where in your code do you initialize it ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for these views in `baseView` and not `itemView`? The views within the list item are not yet added to the RecyclerView for them to be able to be found yet when you're still setting up the ViewHolder. And even if they were, how would it know which list item layout to find them in?

Comment: @forthelulx Sure, I've attached some links to my repository in the original question now.
///

- Tenfour04 Well, I've tried both -- however it was my understanding that it should be itemView, since the views in the inner list will be inside the recyclerview after being inflated. I could be mixing things up, however...

Comment: The views won't be in the RecyclerView at the time the ViewHolder is still being instantiated. And anyway each ViewHolder is going to have a layout with views that have matching names, so you wouldn't know which instance you're getting a reference to even if it did work.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused as to what exactly I'm doing wrong then. This is the exact method I'm using to inflate and populate data from the outer RecyclerView. This seems like it should be working fine, unless there's a difference when trying to use a nested RecyclerView that I'm not accounting for.